# Alternative method for "For Loop"

Tags: vb6, for-loop

I have 4 different values, i want to check 4 values with 4 different combination

Code

```
Dim tot1, tot2, tot3, to4 As Variant
Dim item1, item2, item3, item4 As Variant     

    For Each item1 In tot1
         For Each item2 In tot2
            For Each item3 In tot3
                For Each item4 In tot4
             If item1 = "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '1
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '2
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '3
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 = "All" Then '4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 = "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '1 & 2
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 = "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '1 & 3
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 = "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 = "All" Then '1 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '2 & 3
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 = "All" Then '2 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 = "All" Then '3 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 = "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '1 & 2 & 3
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location <> '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 = "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 = "All" Then '1 & 2 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department <> '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 = "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 = "All" Then '1 & 3 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division <> '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 = "All" And item3 = "All" And item4 = "All" Then '2 & 3 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company <> '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                ElseIf item1 <> "All" And item2 <> "All" And item3 <> "All" And item4 <> "All" Then '1 & 2 & 3 & 4
                    sSQL = "Insert into table1 Select Distinct Emp_Code from Employee Where Company = '" & item1 & "' and Division = '" & item2 & "' and Department = '" & item3 & "' and Location = '" & item4 & "'"
                End If
        Next
            Next
         Next
    Next
```

The above mentioned code is working, but code is very hard for checking the 4 values with combination,
Incase if the checking values is 6 then it will be very difficult to write a combination....

Any other alternative method is available...?

Comment: I believe any programming language of the world has a data structure named `array`.

Comment: Also, building sql strings like this is a **very bad idea**. You're code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you havnt mention the exact structure of your data, otherwise there would have been a better code example, however, try your own code with little modification

```
    Dim tot1 As New Collection, tot2 As New Collection, tot3 As New Collection, tot4 As New Collection
Dim item1, item2, item3, item4 As Variant
Dim str As String

tot1.Add "All"
tot1.Add "2"
tot1.Add "3"
tot1.Add "4"

tot2.Add "1"
tot2.Add "2"
tot2.Add "3"
tot2.Add "All"
tot2.Add "5"

tot3.Add "1"
tot3.Add "All"
tot3.Add "3"
tot3.Add "4"
tot3.Add "5"
tot3.Add "6"

tot4.Add "1"
tot4.Add "All"
tot4.Add "3"


For Each item1 In tot1
     For Each item2 In tot2
        For Each item3 In tot3
            For Each item4 In tot4
               str = vbNullString
               If item1 = "All" Then str = str & "& 1 "
               If item2 = "All" Then str = str & "& 2 "
               If item3 = "All" Then str = str & "& 3 "
               If item4 = "All" Then str = str & "& 4 "
               Debug.Print item1 & "," & item2 & "," & item3 & "," & item4 & " -> " & Mid$(Trim$(str), 2)
            Next
        Next
     Next
Next
```

Comment: That is not my actual code, now i posted my actual code.  I am inserting a value to the table according to the combination....

Comment: How to do change your code for inserting a value into the table....

Comment: Just build up the SQL clause with the relevant where conditions. Instead of adding "& 1" you add "and Division <> '" & item2 & "'" or similar.